# Calculate the rotation performed around a point

Tags: math, geometry

I have two points in 2D space, centred on origin (0,0).  The first point represents the starting location and the second represents the end location. I need to calculate the angle of rotation between the two points, my problem being that the hypoteneuse from each point to (0,0) is not equal.

Could someone tell me how to work out the angle between the two points, bearing in mind that they could be anywhere relative to (0,0).

Many thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say point 1 is (x1,y1) and point 2 is (x2,y2)

The tangent of the Angle from X axis to point 1, relative to (0,0) is y1/x1

The tangent of the Angle from X axis to point 2, relative to (0,0) is y2/x2

Take the arc tangent (is that the right term? Tan-1 on a calculator) to get the actual angle for each, then subtract to get the answer you're looking for

Comment: @Matt W: Don't forget about quadrants where the points are, and about "x = 0" cases.

Comment: Good points. Is arc tangent the right term, do you know? It's been over 20 years since I had a formal maths class, and my memory is a bit rusty

Comment: @Lavir, are you saying that the answer provided by Kevin O' would be different if the points are, say, (10,10) and (-12,-43) ?

Comment: @Kevin Arctangent is the right term. @Matt Ordinary arctan has ambiguities -- you might consider using [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) instead. And obviously there's no defined answer if either of your points coincides with the origin. (Other approaches are possible also, btw -- eg, you could use the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to get the cosine of the angle and take the `acos` of that.)

Comment: If you're going to use arctangents, use `atan2` (if you've got it in your language/library) as it doesn't run into problems when you've got verticals. Plain old `atan` has infinities in the domain, which can be awkward…

Comment: @Matt W: Yes, they would be different.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished taking the arccosine of the normalized **[inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product)** of the two vectors.  That is, given **u** = (u<sub>x</sub>, u<sub>y</sub>) and **v** = (v<sub>x</sub>, v<sub>y</sub>), the angle between the two is given by θ = acos(**u**·**v**/|**u**||**v**|), where **u** · **v** = u<sub>x</sub>v<sub>x</sub> + u<sub>y</sub>v<sub>y</sub> is the dot product of the two and the | | operator is the l<sub>2</sub> normal given by |**u**| = sqrt(u<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + u<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup>).  This will result in the smallest rotation that can be applied to one of the vectors that will make them linear multiples of each other.  Therefore, you may need to fiddle with the sign of θ to make sure you're going in the right direction if you have one you want to start from.

Comment: @Donal Fellows:  Thanks.  I was looking for a way to put a dot in there, but it just kept inserting a big square.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what || means in mathematics. I suspect that this geometry problem wouldn't be a problem if I did. Because of that, I also don't know how to convert it to code (I'm working in lua and C#.)

Comment: @Matt W: |u| means the length of u using normal Cartesian length. That is it's the sqrt(u_x^2 + u_y^2). |u||v| means the product of the length of vector u and the length of vector v.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This not being my usual field, I'm gonna have to thunk on this one a bit.